# The IF....then statement in Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, if-statement, vba

I am testing my understanding on the if then statement, I wrote a little thing down below but when I hit run, nothing happened. I was expecting a msgbox will appear asking me if I want to quit or not and giving me choices to choose. Did I miss anything please. Thanks

```
Sub testifthenelse(bQuit As Boolean)
Dim s As String
s = "Do you want to quit?"
If MsgBox(s, vbYesNo, "Quite?") = vbYes Then
bQuit = True
Else
bQuit = False
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must call it from another sub:

```
Sub main()
    Dim bQuit As Boolean

    testifthenelse bQuit
End Sub
```

while, if you want to run and test it "by itself" then make the argument *optional*

```
Sub testifthenelse(Optional bQuit As Variant)
    Dim s As String

    s = "Do you want to quit?"
    If MsgBox(s, vbYesNo, "Quite?") = vbYes Then
        bQuit = True
    Else
        bQuit = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: But it doesn't make much sense to call it that way - and `bQuit` should still be declared as _Boolean_.

Comment: @Gustav, may be I haven't be clear enough. The two codes I provided are _mutually exclusive_: either you 1) preserve the OP Sub code and then call it as per my _first_ code or 2) you want to test it "by yourself" and then you change its code as per my _second code_. Of course this latter case is just for this so called "by itself" testing purposes, whatever they should be wanted for...

Comment: You were. It was clear to me. Still, there is no reason to not declare `bQuit` as Boolean; it is, as you stated, the _Optional_ that does the trick.

Comment: @Gustav, I actually missed to clarify that by using a `Variant` type for an `Optional` argument you can check for its actually being passed or not to the Sub by means of the `IsMissing()` function, which you couldn't do with any other type. I have it as a habit to do so, that's why I typed like that

Comment: That is true, but it won't fit any purpose here where you in any case will return a Boolean. Tiny details, I know - maybe it is just me ...

Comment: @Gustav, the `Optional` code is for the _"by itself"_ scenario, so no return value expected